# Prevent PHP thumbnail generator response as in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload an image through ajax and needs to get the image URL as response.

code below..

```
$(".filupldt").on('change',function(){

    var file_data=$(this).prop("files")[0];
    var form_data=new FormData();
    form_data.append("file",file_data);
    form_data.append("type",$(this).prev().prev().val());
    form_data.append("primerkey",$(this).prev().val());
    var element = this;

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
        url:'includes/dealerimg.settings.php?operation=savedealerimgeqtype',
        dataType:'json',
        async:false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        data:form_data,
        success:function(response){
          console.log(response);
          //$(element).parent().prev().prev().attr('src',response);
        },
    });
  });
```

PHP Ajax function

```
        $createthumb = new createthumb();
        $todburl =  $this->url;
        $ajaxtype = $_POST['type'];
        $uploads_dir = "../assets/equipmenttype/";
        $uniid = uniqid();
        $now =date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $pkid = $_POST['primerkey'];
        $ext =pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $filename = $pkid."_".$DealerID."_dealerupdate";
        $thumbnamer = $pkid."_".$DealerID."_thumb_dealerupdate_".$uniid.".".$ext;

        $tmpname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $imagename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

        $loc_thumb = $uploads_dir.$thumbnamer;

        $createthumb->create_thumb_with_ratio($tmpname,300,300,$loc_thumb);  //CREATING THUMB
        $createthumb->upload_original(1,$filename,$imagename,$tmpname,$uploads_dir);//for upload original

        $thumnametodb = $thumbnamer;
        $orinametodb = $filename."_".$imagename;

        $data = ['dddd'=>$todburl."assets/equipmenttype/".$thumbnamer];
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
```

This function working perfectly and creating thumb in my required folder.

But this is an ajax page and I want to show the image name as response.

In this case the ajax response is like below attached image.

[image]

How can i solve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like somewhere in your code it is outputting the contents of the uploaded file.  maybe in `create_thumb_with_ratio` or `upload_original` .. if you scroll to the bottom of the response does it show the image's file name?

Comment: no dude. its only containing some special characters and finally my response text as I am given n code.

Comment: Request a json data type instead of html. In your php, add headers to set your content type to json. It sounds for me that you've forced to return als image (binary), but your request expects ascii.

Comment: check the response without echo statement and let us know

Comment: @Venkatraman no response. its showing as blank

Comment: @Schellingerht, Edited question as your wish, please check.

Comment: try echo one by one for like echo $todburl; then

echo "assets/equipmenttype/"; then

echo $thumbnamer; and let us know

Comment: @Venkatraman, added response in question like you said. please check

Comment: what was the response for each echo ?, are you getting binary dat even for string echo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100116/discussion-between-jishad-p-and-venkatraman).

Comment: _“no dude. its only containing some special characters”_ – but yes, dude – that totally looks like binary image data, not just “some special characters”. (But since you totally failed to mention any details about your `createthumb` class, we can only speculate whether direct output of the image data is the default, influenced by a parameter, or …)

Answer (score 0):

You said that *you want to show the image name as response* :

Then just

```
echo $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

then in your script you get the image name as response with :

```
 success:function(response){
          console.log('Image Name = '+response);             
 }
```

Your current response is JSON representation (*`json_encode($data)`*) & not the image's name.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some output is braking the response data. To be sure that nothing prints on the response page try putting **ob_start()** and **ob_end_clean()**

```
ob_start();
//...
// your code here
//...
$data['dddd'] = $todburl."assets/equipmenttype/".$thumbnamer;
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($data);
```